# how to enable only my ip for google compute instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

Under Networking > Firewall Rules

Created a firewall rule and now its `0.0.0.0/0` with a port `tcp:80`

Now i would want only my workstation which as say xx.xx.xxx.xxx public IP to access that instance. I know we can give a range/CIDR but how to enable/whitelist only my machines IP.

Comment: Just a guess but I think you can specify a single source by using a /32 subnet mask.  0.0.0.0/32  See the table at this page: http://whatismyipaddress.com/cidr

Comment: Thanks that did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify just the IP in the sourceRanges field by appending a /32, e.g. 1.2.3.4/32.